# Pyautogui second click doesn't work, how to resolve this?

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.click(1129, 89)
pyautogui.click(1420, 410)
```

I'm trying to automate something and I wrote this very simple code. But my problem is that for the first part the cursor goes there and click, but for the second time it only goes there but doesn't click. What is the problem with that?

I tried putting a time.sleep(1) between the two click and also tried these codes:

1st:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller
import time

time.sleep(3)

mouse = Controller()

mouse.position = (1129, 89)
mouse.click(button='left')

time.sleep(1)

mouse.position = (1420, 410)
mouse.click(button='left')
```

2nd:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
import time

time.sleep(3)

mouse = Controller()

mouse.position = (1129, 89)
mouse.click(Button.left)

time.sleep(1)

mouse.position = (1420, 410)
mouse.click(Button.left)
```

3rd:

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.mouseDown(1129, 89)
pyautogui.mouseUp(1129, 89)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.mouseDown(1420, 410)
pyautogui.mouseUp(1420, 410)
```

Comment: how do you know that it doesn't click? Maybe there is no object to click. What do you try to click?